# Running Python programs in python.exe, the command prompt, and IDLE

Tags: python-2.7

Let me preface this post that I am incredibly new to python. I took a course in codeacademy but haven't actually used python on my own computer until now. Let me also explain to everyone that my coding experience is limited to VBA and excel. I have very little knowledge of how to use the command prompt, how libraries work, etc, etc.

I'm having some issues. I've changed my directory to recognize python when I type python in my command prompt. Then I can do simple things like

```
print "hello"
```

however if i write something like this

```
def firstfunction(t):
         print t+5
         return
firstfunction(5)
```

I would expect this to print the number 10, however I get the following error:

File"stdin", line 4
first function(5)
^
syntaxerror: invalid syntax

However if I use this in IDLE and run it it works fine.

Next I've saved some python programs I wrote. One I saved as Hello.py

i want to run this code from my python exe or from the command prompt but can't figure out how.

Please any answers helpful, if you use computer lingo, try and keep it as simple as possible. I'm super new!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the location of python is not included in your path, add it. But in any case, you should be able to run this successfully from the directory containing your python.exe.

e.g, if python lives in C:\Python27:

```
cd C:\Python27
python mypythonscript.py
```

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work from my command prompt. How do I get it to work from python.exe?

Comment: Also, how why would this not work in the command prompt or the python.exe:

Comment: def firstfunction(t):
         print t+5
         return
firstfunction(5)

Comment: @tkosinki Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @JoshDautel Works for me just as you wrote it both via the command line and via Idle. You might try reinstalling? That it is not working for you makes me think there's some sort of PATH issue.